# BDC model/search connector and multi value field with refinment

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

**BDC model:**
My BDC model's entity has a property named Color.
The TypeName is specified as System.String[].

```
<TypeDescriptor Name="Color" TypeName="System.String[]">
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="RequiredInForms" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
  </Properties>
</TypeDescriptor>
```

**Database:**
In my database (my BDC content source) I added column values like this one:

```
;#Blue;#Green;#Yellow;#
```

**Search Schema**
I created a new managed property and enabled multiple values (and also refinable - active, queryable, retrievable, safe).

**Search Results**
Filtering on a specific color via search works.
Example: RsExpAdvWorksProductColor:"blue"

**Search Refinement**
However I cannot refine on colors.
Adding a refiner on my Managed Property shows up like that:

```
Color
;#Blue;#Green;#Yellow;#  
;#Green;#Yellow;#  
;#Red;#Green;#Yellow;#Blue;#Black;#Cyan;#
```

Obviously the single values are not treated as such - the whole "string" of "special-delimiter" separated values is being shown as a refinment criteria.

**Any hints?**

**Update 2015-03-20:** I took a closer look at the built-in multi choice columns. In search results they are being returned as "Value1;#Value2;#" and so on. Basically there is a *trailing* `Red;#Blue;#` separator - no *leading* `;#Red;#Blue;#` one. Much to my regret that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: How have you been able to get it working with TypeName="System.String[]"? All I'm getting is `Error while crawling LOB contents. Error caused by exception: System.InvalidOperationException There is an error in XML document` when I try to use a collection property.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2015-03-20:** Surprise surprise. It is in fact "working as designed" (like so many things in SharePoint :P). What I am looking for has to be dealt with separately. It behaves exactly the same with built-in multi choice fields so **there is nothing wrong with my BDC/Search integration**.

**Regarding the refiner, have a look at the following links...**

- http://www.eliostruyf.com/part-6-create-multi-value-search-refiner-control/
- https://hyankov.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/sharepoint-2013-refiner-multi-value-contains-instead-of-an-equals/